# Is there a way to suppress :OutputWarning: in Pact verify?

Tags: pact-lang

I have some models (property tests and invariants) in my module, and I want them to be verified using Pact's formal verification. When running `(verify 'my-module)`, where `'my-module` depends on the `coin-v4` contract, I am receiving output warnings:

```
:OutputWarning: Unsupported operation: validate-principal: substituting True
:OutputWarning: Unsupported operation: is-charset: substituting True
```

These warnings are being emitted by the coin contract, not my contract. Can I suppress these warnings?

Comment: Why are you running verify, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have some models and property tests in my module, and I want them to be formally verified.